# Загрузка файла через js

Tags: javascript

У меня есть сервер на golang . Когда из браузера идет обращение к серверу по пути `http://localhost:8081/generateJSON` на сервере генерируется json файл и сразу же отдается - браузер предлагает его скачать.

На клиенте имеется кнопка сгенерировать json, которая как раз выполняет такой запрос :

```
fetch('/generateJSON')
```

Мне нужно чтобы появлялось диалоговое окно по типу ("сохранить как")
Я `могу` создать ссылку на этот файл на сервере, конечно, но мне нужно, чтобы все делалось именно при нажатии на кнопку без создания дополнительных элементов

Comment: Поясните, что именно Вы хотите? "не созданием ссылки на файл" - а как?

Comment: @Yaant подправил вопрос, надеюсь так более понятно что я имел ввиду :)

Comment: Спасибо, так действительно намного лучше. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел подходящее мне решение, может тоже кому поможет

```
fetch('http://localhost:{$PORT}/generateJSON')
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(data => {
           let link = document.createElement('a');
           link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
           link.download = 'doc.xml';
           document.body.appendChild(link);

           link.click();

           document.body.removeChild(link);
        })
```

Не обошлось без создания ссылки, однако она не ведет на сервер